# Updating imageViews in onTouchEvent in realtime

Tags: java, android

In my onTouchEvent method (in a class that extends Activity), I have some imageViews that change one by one, which is done by waiting a little before executing the next change.

```
//in the onTouchEvent method
//ivList is an arrayList of imageViews
ivList.get(0).setImageResource(R.drawable.drawable1);
synchronized (this) {
    try {
        wait(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
ivList.get(1).setImageResource(R.drawable.drawable2);
```

However, when this is executed, the changes only take place once onTouchEvent is concluded, so the result is a minor delay and then both imageViews change at once, as opposed to one imageView changing, a minor delay, and then the second one changes. Can someone explain how to fix this?

Comment: What parameters does the `wait()` method take specifically?

Comment: the parameter is (long timeout). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Comment: 500? How long do you want the delay to be...it takes the parameter in milliseconds so 500 is nearly instant to the human eye. Are you just trying to prevent thread lock?

Comment: The parameter is irrelevant. Even if I make it 1000 (1 second), the problem remains. The imageViews only get updated after onTouchEvent returns true, as opposed to instantaneously.

Comment: do you mean you cannot see R.drawable.drawable1 but R.drawable.drawable2 only?

Comment: No, what I want is for the first imageView to change, a delay to occur, and then for the second imageView to change. What is currently happening is that a delay happens FIRST, and then both of them change at the same time. However, I can see both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you should not use wait() because it will block the main thread

```
ivList.get(0).setImageResource(R.drawable.drawable1); // this is doing in main thread
synchronized (this) {
    try {
        wait(500); // this blocks the main thread
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
ivList.get(1).setImageResource(R.drawable.drawable2); // this is also doing in main thread
```

try following

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ivList.get(1).setImageResource(R.drawable.drawable2);
    }
};
ivList.get(0).setImageResource(R.drawable.drawable1);
// no synchronized is needed
new Handler().postDelayed(r,500); // call to change the image after 500s
```

of cause your Runnable and Handler can create else where so that you do not need to create them every time the onTouchEvent is trigeered

okay , if you are going to make it work for 10 images.

```
// these are local variables
//create a contant int array for the 10 images
int[] imgs = {R.drawable.drawable1 , R.drawable.drawable2 ,....,R.drawable.drawable10};
int count = 0; // counting which image should show
// local variable ends

// initialize
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (count < 9){
                count++;
                ivList.get(count).setImageResource(imgs[count]);
                handler().postDelayed(r,500);
            }
        }
    };

// in your touch event

ivList.get(0).setImageResource(R.drawable.drawable1);
// no synchronized is needed
handler().postDelayed(r,500); // call to change the image after 500s
```

Comment: What would I do if I wanted to do this with 10 imageViews?

Comment: you mean 1 after 1 for 10 images?

Comment: yes, would I have to create separate runnables each time?